# How to retrieve historical imagery from web mapping services?

Tags: google-maps-api, bing-maps, history

Is there a way to retrieve historical imagery from Google/Bing/Yandex mapping services through their APIs?

For example, I'd like to show on my website imagery from 2005.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may not be the exact answer, but may help you on your journey. Take a look at this Article on [How to View Historical Satellite Imagery in Google Earth](http://voices.yahoo.com/how-view-historical-satellite-imagery-google-12037398.html?cat=59) or Explore Google Earth's [Historical Imagery](http://www.google.ca/earth/explore/showcase/historical.html).

Comment: Google Maps API can be used in 'Earth' mode see 'Time Machine' http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?exp=earth#time_and_historical_imagery_ui Enable then enter a YEAR date (2005).

Comment: Please note that the first link in this answer now resolves to just Yahoo's front page.  (That's why it's always preferable to not just link to an answer, but to include some background as well, in case the link goes bad.)